# Rspec 2.10.1, Rails 3.2.13 - ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm writing an rspec test that sends a JSON via POST to a member route end point.  But I'm getting a "no route matches" error when I do so.  I'm not sure if there's something I need to add because this endpoint is a member route, or I'm just missing some HTTP request headers because I'm sending a JSON.  Please help.

This is what I have:

Spec:

```
describe "#endpoint" do
 context "type 1" do

  before(:each) do
    post :create, @params.merge(:abc => {:first_user_id => @user1.id, :second_user_id => @user2.id})
    @mashup = assigns(:mashup)
  end

  it "should post the results successfully" do

    units = [...]
    users = [...]
    params = @params.merge(:mashup_outcome => {:status => "success", :assetName => "MashupAssetName", :winningUserId => @user1.id}, :mashup_id => @mashup.id, :version_number => 1, :user_id => @user1.id, :id => @mashup.id ,:users => :users).to_json

     @request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"

     #had to have a param key for my params below in order to bypass the NoMethodError
     #In actual request body, it's just a JSON
     post :over, :mashup => params


    @mashups.in_progress.should be_false
  end
end

context "type 2" do

  before(:each) do
     ...
  end

  it "should post the results correctly" do 
      ...
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
namespace :mashup do
  resources :mashups do
    member do
      post :endpoint
    end
end
```

Controller:

```
def endpoint
    if @mashup.complete_mashup(params)
      render :json => api_success(@mashup.dpoints)
    else
      render :json => api_error({})
    end
  end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: post :endpoint, :mashup => params
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:mashup => "{...<JSON>...}", :controller => "api/mashup/mashups", :action => "endpoint"}
```

Comment: if you have a member method, shouldn't it have at least one :id in the path?

Comment: Shouldn't rails routing handle that?

Comment: no. that is part of the path and not of the payload that you post!

Comment: hmmm..when I edit the post request to: 'post :over, :id => @user.id, :mashup => params'                          I get the error:  'Failure/Error: 
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass'